# Linux capabilities for modifying files owned by root?

Tags: linux, capabilities

Is there any [linux capability](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) to enable normal users to write into root owned files like `/etc/resolv.conf` and /etc/fstab`?

Comment: You can use `sudo` to write as root (Assuming `/etc/sudoers` allows you to).

Comment: If you're running a Linux distro which uses NetworkManager you don't even have to let users change this file. NM will manage it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There's a capability that allows accessing arbitrary files regardless of permissions (`CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE`), but it's almost equivalent to granting root access (if you can overwrite `/etc/passwd`, with most configurations, you're in): it's only useful for processes that perform a specific task (for example a backup program), not to grant to a user. And there's no capability that allows bypassing permissions for specific files: capabilities are boolean, they aren't parametrized by a list of files. It would be pretty much pointless anyway because there's already a mechanism to allow users to write to specific files: permissions.

Create a group, add the users to the group, and grant the group write access to the file.

```
addgroup fstab-writers
adduser alice fstab-writers     # Note that this only takes effect when alice logs in, not in her already-running session(s).
chgrp fstab-writers /etc/fstab
chmod g+w /etc/fstab
```

If more than one group needs particular permissions on the file, use an access control list instead of `chgrp` and `chmod`.

```
setfacl -m g:fstab-writers:rw /etc/fstab
```

Note that if a system program overwrites the file in question, there's no guarantee that it'll reproduce the group ownership or the access control list. But if that's the case, you probably shouldn't be modifying this file manually anyway.

Also note that for both `/etc/fstab` and `/etc/resolv.conf`, there are well-established mechanisms that don't require giving users write permissions.

- Giving a user write permission on `/etc/fstab` is equivalent to allowing them to run arbitrary commands as root. The easiest way is to mount a filesystem image with a setuid root executable, and there are others. If you want to allow users to mount filesystems, they can use [udisks](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udisks) (which is what desktop environments use under the hood) or [`pmount`](https://wiki.debian.org/pmount).
- `/etc/resolv.conf` is typically managed automatically by [NetworkManager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetworkManager), which can be controlled by non-root users. This is what desktop environments use under the hood and there is also has a command line interface (`nmcli`). Even in the absence of NetworkManager, many distributions ship [resolvconf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolvconf) to manage it automatically when the network connection changes.

Comment: Thank you! is resolvconf shipped by default in most modern widely used distros like anything Debian/Ubuntu based, Archlinux, NixOS and Fedora?

Comment: Well, I just found out that `resolvconf` needs root also

Comment: While I agree that using a capability that allows this, will give too much permission, and is not the way to go. The non-existent capability is `CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE`, or will a bit less privilege `CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH`

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Good point! I mixed bypassing access control on all files, and bypassing access control on specific files.